# Encoding a file to base 64 Nodejs

Tags: node.js, encoding

I used the code below to encode a file to base64.

```js
var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
```

I figured that in the file we have issues with `“”` and `‘’` characters, but it’s fine with `"`

When we have `It’s`, node encodes the characters, but when I decode, I see it as
`Itâ€™s`

Here's the javascript I'm using to decode:

```js
fs.writeFile(reportPath, body.buffer, {encoding: 'base64'}
```

So, once the file is encoded and decoded, it becomes unusable with these funky characters - `Itâ€™s`

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that helped.

```
var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);

// Remove the non-standard characters
var tmp  = bitmap.toString().replace(/[“”‘’]/g,'');

// Create a buffer from the string and return the results
return new Buffer(tmp).toString('base64');
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work.
Sample script:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const filepath = './testfile'
//write "it's" into the file
fs.writeFileSync(filepath,"it's")

//read the file
const file_buffer  = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
//encode contents into base64
const contents_in_base64 = file_buffer.toString('base64');
//write into a new file, specifying base64 as the encoding (decodes)
fs.writeFileSync('./fileB64',contents_in_base64,{encoding:'base64'})
//file fileB64 should now contain "it's"
```

I suspect your original file does not have utf-8 encoding, looking at your decoding code:
`fs.writeFile(reportPath, body.buffer, {encoding: 'base64'})`

I am guessing your content comes from a http request of some sorts so it is possible that the content is not utf-8 encoded. Take a look at this:
https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index if charset is not specified Content-Type text/ uses ISO-8859-1.

Comment: thankyou for pointing me to the right direction. I had to first remove the non standard ascii characters which are apostrophes (single and double)  and then encode to base 64.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide base64 encoding to the readFileSync function itself.

```
const fileDataBase64 = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'base64')
```