# How to download a file stored using GridFS and returned using GraphQL in the React/Javascript Client?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, gridfs

I have a file in my database stored using GridFS and the mongoDB gives me a `chunks` and a `files`.

`chunks`

```
_id: <int>
files_id: <int>
n: 0,
data: Binary(<string>, 0)
```

`files`

```
_id: <id>
length: <int>
chunkSize: <int>
uploadDate: <date>
filename: <string>
md5: <string>
```

Is there a way to download this file in the client through GraphQL? Like for example returning a chunk and converting it in the frontend side for the client to download? Or maybe a way send a file directly to graphql and make the client download it (so far everything points that it's not possible)?

Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: return url/id only (GraphQL) for some service (GET) returning file from GridFS - different headers required for graphql response and files

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like putting the file in some remote file server then make the graphql return the url?

Comment: not, return some id (or full url) to other (not `/graphql`) endpoint (e.g. `/document?id=someId`) returning (for given id, not easy to guess or auth required) content/file directly from GridFS

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just I converted the file into a base64 string ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763987/14389341)). Then return the string in the resolver.

```
const file_buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
const contents_in_base64 = file_buffer.toString('base64');
return contents_in_base64;
```

Alternatively, if you don't have access to the file same as the original question then you can

```
chunk.data.toString('base64'));
```

Then on the front-end, I just put the base64 on an anchor tag ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336952/14389341)).

```
<a download={`${filename}.pdf`} href={`data:application/pdf;base64,${base64pdf}`} title='Download pdf document' />
```

Comment: suitable for small files